# Change default ViewCube Orientation

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using the Forge Viewer to display simple geometry extractions from buildings.
However, when loading them the orientation of the model/view cube is not matching the expected use case (see image).
Basically I would need to swap the "Front View" with the "Top View".
Is this possible to achieve such a thing through e.g. default settings on the viewer object?

My set up is basically identical to the one in this 3rd-party react wrapper of the Forge Viewer: https://github.com/outer-labs/react-forge-viewer

Thank you already very much.

Daniel

EDIT: The model is in STP format
[image: Default orientation when loading the model]

Comment: May I know what the model format it is in the above snapshot?

Comment: Ah sorry for the late reply. The model is in STP format, it is one of the default export formats provided by the library I'm using  (pythonOCC)

Comment: I needed to set the initial orientation facing "right" so used @EasonKang's answer `viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function (event) { setTimeout(() => { viewer.setViewCube("right"); }, 1000); } );` to do that

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can archive this with following steps via Viewer APIs after the model is loaded completely and can be separated into two parts.

1. (Preproccess) Get the `Front` view state of the Viewer that your want to make it as the `Top`:

   a. Orient the current view to `Front` view: `viewer.setViewCube( 'front' )`.
   b. Obtain current view statue of the viewport: `var viewState = .getState( { viewport: true } )`.
   c. Save this `viewState` to somewhere, your js file or database.
2. Restore view state and set it as the `Top` view:

   a. Obtain the `viewState` from somewhere (e.g. js file or database) that you got from the step1.
   b. Restore view state via `viewer.restoreState( viewState )`.
   c. Set the current view as `Top` view: `viewer.autocam.setCurrentViewAsTop()`.
   d. Set the current view as Home to avoid the state of the viewcube to be reset: `viewer.autocam.setCurrentViewAsHome()`.

The code snippet for step2:

```
viewer.addEventListener(
    Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
    function( event ) {
        console.log( '%cGEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT: !!!Geometries loaded!!!', 'color: green;' );

        setTimeout(() => {
            const onOrientTopViewCompleted = function() {
                viewer.removeEventListener(
                    Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_TRANSITION_COMPLETED,
                    onOrientTopViewCompleted
                );

                viewer.autocam.setCurrentViewAsTop();
                viewer.autocam.setCurrentViewAsHome();

                console.log( 'CAMERA_TRANSITION_COMPLETED' );
            };

            viewer.addEventListener(
                Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_TRANSITION_COMPLETED,
                onOrientTopViewCompleted
            );

            var viewState = '....'; //!<< the view state of the original `Front` view.

            viewer.restoreState( viewState )
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I will give it a try as soon as possible and update.